# Get filenames from directory path or .txt file - Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

Currently I have a FileListGenerator.bat which looks like so:

```
dir /b /s >>FilesDirectoryList.txt
```

Returning a list of file directories looking like.

```
C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\Customers\Customer1
C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\Customers\Customer2
C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\Customers\FileListGenerator.bat
C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\Customers\FilesDirectoryList.txt
C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\Customers\Customer1\Analysys Mason
C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\Customers\Customer1\More
C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\Customers\Customer1\Other
C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\Customers\Customer1\Analysys Mason\Crook _ Hatchet blk white font.psd
C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\Customers\Customer1\More\Crook _ Hatchet lot.png
C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\Customers\Customer1\More\Crook _ Hatchet midd.png
C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\Customers\Customer1\Other\Crook _ Hatchet bigger.png
C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\Customers\Customer1\Other\Crook _ Hatchet botton final.png
C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\Customers\Customer2\Analysys Mason
C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\Customers\Customer2\More
C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\Customers\Customer2\Other
C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\Customers\Customer2\Analysys Mason\LiberalHand-Bld.otf
C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\Customers\Customer2\Analysys Mason\LiberalHand-Rg.ttf
C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\Customers\Customer2\Other\Crook _ Hatchet new font.png
```

Is there a way to either run a script against the .txt file or in command line to return just the file names?

Comment: in PowerShell, it would be: `gci . | select FullName | out-file .\somefile.txt -force`

Comment: that just returns the top level of file names in need subfolders too

Comment: then you just need to add `-r` to `gci .` so it's `gci . -r | [...]` the `-r` switch means recursive (btw: the `.` means the current directory, you can also put a path in there instead of the `.` - same for the `.` in `out-file`

Answer (score 1):

Try this in command line:

```
for /r %a in (*) do @echo %~nxa >>FilesDirectoryList.txt
```

In batch file (need to double the percentage signs):

```
for /r %%a in (*) do @echo %%~nxa >>FilesDirectoryList.txt
```

Based on answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396761/how-to-list-all-files-in-directory-subdirectory-without-path-name-cmd)

Comment: would i just add dir to the start to run from current directory?

Comment: it should be ran, as is, from the top directory you want to search down from. Much as you did with your `dir` command originally.

Comment: dir(for /r %a in (*) do @echo %~nxa) >>test.txt just returns : Volume in drive C has no label, Directory of C:\......

Comment: Remove the dir command section. Its not necessary. I have updated the post with how to output it to a file. Just copy that into command line and run it. http://i.imgur.com/CLpLkS3.png

Comment: for /r %a in (*) do @echo %~nxa >>test.txt doesn't create the .txt file

Comment: Is it possible UAC is preventing creation of the file at the root of your C:\ drive? Have you tried running it in your user folder?

Comment: Just ran it from my desktop and still wont create :(

Comment: I must admit I am confused. I have tried it on my own system and it worked. What version of Windows are you running?

Comment: windows 10 is what im currently using

Comment: Ah - then accept my apologies - I have tested this under Windows 7 and currently do not have a Windows 10 system to hand to test (office is W7 only).

Comment: One note - is this in a batch file? If so you may need to double up the percentage signs: `for /r %%a in (*) do @echo %%~nxa >>FilesDirectoryList.txt`

Comment: Ahh ok ill try that now

Comment: Still no joy, I may have to test on my computer at home as its running windows 7

Answer (score 1):

If you need to display ONLY a certain filetype like .txt, .doc, .dll, .exe ..etc, you can use `dir` command and adjust the parameters as you need.

Here is a simple example: 
Suppose I need to display a list of text files names only in a directory.
I can use this command

> `dir *.txt /b`

and it'll display something like this :

> file1.txt
>
> file2.txt
>
> file3.txt
>
> file4.txt
>
> ...etc

you can use it in a batch file as is, (something like this):

```
@Echo off

:: display a list of *.txt files
dir *.txt /b
```

or you can expand the code as you wish ( something like this):

```
@Echo off

:: save a list of *.txt files into another text file inside C:
dir *.txt /b > C:\results.txt
```

It depends on your goal and how you want to achieve it.

You can learn more about DIR command line from here : 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755121(v=ws.11).aspx

Answer (score 0):

In Windows PowerShell, you can do this.

Just the file names with full path:

```
(gci -r | ? {!$_.PsIsContainer}).FullName | Out-File test.txt -Force
```

Just the file names showing the name and extension only:

```
(gci -r | ? {!$_.PsIsContainer}).Name | Out-File test.txt -Force
```

Comment: Am I able to make this into a .bat file? or something similar to be run on click?

Comment: @BenAllington You can put into a .ps1 file. (These are more advanced than batch files.) Of course, if you are running a very old version of Windows PowerShell, you need to open it as an admin and issue the following command: `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` This commend needs to be run once in a computer's lifetime.

Comment: theres no need for the foreach, i'd rather go with my approach in the comments.

Comment: @SimonS Your approach in the comments is flawed. It does not exclude the folders as the OP requested. The OP wants "just the file names" not folder names. In addition, your approach adds a blank line, a "FullName" line and then a "--------" line.

Comment: I don't see a problem with the fullname ----, that's just PowerShell standard. if you don't want that i'd do it like this `(gci . -r | ? {!$_.PsIsContainer}).Name | out-file .\xyz.txt -force`

Comment: @SimonS Very well. I'll update my answer. I upvoted your comment.